# Error performing function deploy for Cloud Functions

Tags: angular, firebase, google-cloud-messaging, google-cloud-functions

I am trying to deploy the following function below but an error is occurring and I am not able to identify the problem.

Below the code that is inside the **index.js** file.

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require("firebase-admin");

// // Create and Deploy Your First Cloud Functions
// // https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/write-firebase-functions
//

exports.fcmSend = functions.database.ref('/messages/{userId}/{messageId}').onCreate(event => {

  const message = event.after.val();
  const userId = event.params.userId;

  const payload = {
    notification: {
      title: message.title,
      body: message.body,
      icon: "https://placeimg.com/250/250/people"
    }
  };

  return Promise.all([]);


  admin.database().ref(`/fcmTokens/${userId}`).once('value')
    .then(token => {
      token.val();
    })
    .then(userFcmToken => {
      return admin.messaging().sendToDevice(userFcmToken, payload);
    })
    .then(res => {
      console.log("Sent Successfully", res);
    })
    .catch(err => {
      console.log(err);
    });

});
```

**Displays the following error:**

**Error in CMD:**

```
 27:15  error  Each then() should return a value or throw  promise/always-return

✖ 1 problem (1 error, 0 warnings)
```

Answer (score 1):

The error message is saying that you're not returning a value a `then` callback.  You have two that are not returning a value (or throwing an exception).  See my comments in your code:

```
  admin.database().ref(`/fcmTokens/${userId}`).once('value')
    .then(token => {
      token.val();   // this is not returning a value
    })
    .then(userFcmToken => {
      return admin.messaging().sendToDevice(userFcmToken, payload);
    })
    .then(res => {
      console.log("Sent Successfully", res);   // this is not returning a value
    })
    .catch(err => {
      console.log(err);
    });
```

Even worse, you are returning before any of that code is ever going to be executed:

```
return Promise.all([]);
```

Comment: Okay, I've corrected this but I'm not able to do that every time a message is written through onCreate, run the `admin.messaging (). SendToDevice () `function, error is occurring, what would be the correct way to do this?